# org.robolectric:shadows-supportv4 doesn't support Jetpack(androidx)

Tags: android, robolectric, android-jetpack, androidx

Main repo: org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0-alpha-4-SNAPSHOT **works with androidx**
org.robolectric:shadows-supportv4  **doesn't work, ie:**

`class TestSupportFragment extends  androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`

**doesn't work -**----> `SupportFragmentController.of(new TestSupportFragment())`

any snapshot for **shadows-supportv4** ?

[issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3985)

Comment: Did you solve this issue?